# converting epoch time in human readable format

Tags: python, python-3.x, epoch

I want to convert epoch time into human readable format, when I am giving random epoch time for example the below one

```
 epoch1 = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(1347517370).strftime('%c')
 print(epoch1)
```

then this is working fine.
But, If i am using my epoch time which i am retrieving through an API. this doesn't work and gives me error

```
epoch1 = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(1563924640001).strftime('%c')
print(epoch1)
```

what is the issue with this? even if I am passing the variable it doesn't work.

```
epoch1 = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(epoch).strftime('%c')
```

I want to get all the epoch time from the API and convert it in human readable format.

Any help highly appreciated

error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/kiran.tanweer/Documents/Python Scripts/siem/01_GetOffenses.py", line 1042, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:/Users/kiran.tanweer/Documents/Python Scripts/siem/01_GetOffenses.py", line 953, in main
    epoch1 = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(1563924640001).strftime('%c')
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument
```

Comment: Your code `epoch1 = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(1563924640001).strftime('%c')` gets me to `ValueError: year 51528 is out of range`. It may be that your timestamp is in `ms` instead of `s`? Either way, I do not see why are you getting `OSError`.

Comment: try changing `1563924640001` to `156392464000`. If it's correct then you should exclude last digit

Comment: @AnjaneyuluBatta unless he is dealing with relatively far predictions (e.g. Year 6925?), I would tend to believe your approach may not be what OP wants.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're getting millisecond epoch time from that API.

Divide by 1000 to get seconds which `fromtimestamp` accepts:

```py
>>> datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(1563924640001 / 1000).strftime('%c')
'Wed Jul 24 02:30:40 2019'
```

Comment: It's a valid hypothesis, but why would `1563924640001` throw `OSError` rather than just giving a date in the very far future? In my system, throws a `ValueError` until year `9999`.

Comment: @norok2 1563924640001 is in the year 51,528.

Comment: I get it, but why `OSError`?

Comment: OP is on Windows; the underlying date APIs work a little differently.

Answer (score 2):

Try like below

```
>>> import datetime
>>> datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(1347517370).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
'2012-09-13 14:22:50' # Local time
```

In your case `1563924640001` to `156392464000`

```
epoch1 = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(156392464000).strftime('%c')
print(epoch1)
# output: Sun Nov 18 04:36:40 6925
```